# Dynamic Importing and Loading of Components in Angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, loading, lazy-evaluation

I would like to create a sort of portal that will load angular components without explicitly importing them. Is there a quick and easy sample to do this? I see the ComponentFactoryResolver may be used for this but I need the components to be written in separate file or read from directory and then imported and loaded on demand. Can someone give good examples or point to the most minimal steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript 2.4 now supports dynamic [import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html). It is possible to import module or components dynamically using this function. for example:

you can read a json file and pass the module or component URL in the following code, where `getModules()` is a service function

```
 this.apiService.getModules().subscribe(
        data =>{       
                data.forEach(moduleUrl => {
                    import(''+moduleUrl).then( module => {                        
                       console.log(module);
                   });
                });

            }
        },
        error => {}

    );
```